# Linking Static Libraries in Xcode

Tags: xcode

I am trying to link the opengl image loading library Soil to my Xcode project, but I am finding this very difficult.  I have tried to link the .a file but this does not work.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the supplied .a file isn't for Mac; you can instead make a new Xcode (BSD C library) project, include the source+ headers, and use this in a larger project.

If you're using Xcode 4, this [link](http://carbonfivecommunity.wordpress.com/2011/04/04/using-open-source-static-libraries-in-xcode-4/) will help with the general approach to using / creating your own static libraries, and using them.